# Is taxidermy kosher?

Tags: halacha, death, animals

Is the art of taxidermy kosher?  What about keeping animals that are stuffed in your house?  My family has recently become more observant and my brother wanted to get several stuffed animals, fish, etc. but we weren't sure if there was a problem with that.

Comment: They have them at the Torah Musem ,no?

Comment: However ,I could see it being a haskfa problem

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Leah, and thanks for bringing your question here. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. Please note that the site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends, and consult your rabbi for practical guidance.

Answer (score 3):

While this is not direct proof that taxidermy is OK, the upcoming Jewish Museum of Natural history, to be built in Bet Shemesh, plans to use taxidermy mountings. See [This article](http://zootorah.com/assets/media/essays/ExoticShofars.pdf).

Comment: Any reason to think an religious authority approved the presence of mountings?

Comment: @msh210 - I wouldn't know. I know that Rabbi Slifkin, who seems to be the main person "in charge" of the museum, may have received or is attempting to receive "hashgacha", IF it is necessary in the first place. Rabbi Slifkin is a "controversial" figure, though, I don't quite understand why some disapprove of him. I find his articles and work fascinating, esp. the one about Shofrot, that I linked to.